# Parallax effect is interfering with smooth scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, parallax

**Okay, so I fixed the smooth scrolling problem by taking all the content out of the container div "box" and having the java call scrollbar data from (window) -- and got the parallax working in firefox by adding -moz-transform instead of just using webkit, thanks ahren –**

I've been working on redesigning a net-label to have a parallax effect.  Here is a link to what I've done so far:

<strike>http://www.sasparillarootcoyote.com/parallax_experiment/index2.html</strike>(**Link unavailable**)

I've gotton the parallax effect to work exactly how I want it to, only to find that it doesn't work at all in firefox. Anyone have any ideas about how I can fix this without using an entirely different method to create the parallax effect?

Here's the parallax script -- I'm using JQuery 8.1.3

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#box").scroll(function () {
            s = $("#box").scrollTop();
            $("#hideedges").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/1)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb1").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/1.6)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb2").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/2)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb3").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/4)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb4").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb5").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/50)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb6").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/16)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb7").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb8").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/9)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb9").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/3)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb10").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/44)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb11").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/9)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb12").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/500)  + "px)");
            $("#thumb13").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor13").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/1.6)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor1").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/2)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor2").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/4)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor3").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor4").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/50)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor5").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/16)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor6").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor7").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/9)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor8").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/100)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor9").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/44)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor10").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/9)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor11").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/500)  + "px)");
            $("#thumbcolor12").css("-webkit-transform","translateY(" +  (s/24)  + "px)");

        })

    })

</script>
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: You need to throttle your scroll handler... And the reason it doesn't work in firefox is because you're using only `webkit` prefixes for your CSS...

Comment: Not related, but you can condense this code by grouping elements that will have the same value `$('#thumb2, #thumbcolor1').css(...`

Comment: @Shmiddty and cache those selected elements!

Comment: the parallax works fine, it's just that the image isn't scrolling down the page. Agree with Shmiddty on the condensing, and Matt on the caching.

Comment: The caching could actually be a substantial performance improvement.

Comment: @Matt Ball -- what does that mean, caching the selected elements ?

Comment: @user2121528 Currently, you are querying the DOM for each of those elements every time the scroll event is fired. If you instead create variables outside of the scroll handler then use the variables, jQuery won't have to re-query the DOM to get to them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

to your #one img will keep the image on the screen at all times.